# Sheet.Activate is not working in Office 2010 - 64 bit

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a Macro which is working just perfect in my machine (Windows 64 bit & Office 32 bit)

But client is facing issue. He is having Windows 64 bit & Office 64 bit.

Don't know why but `Sheet.Activate` is not working on his machine. Refer below screen prints.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your input, I cannot find back a declaration of "Recordsheet". 
Since you input this code in the event routine "Workbook_open", I doubt that you did the declaration anywhere.

If you want to apply

```
RecordSheet.Activate
```

The least thing you should do is:

```
Set oRecordSheet = thisworkbook.sheets("Records") 
oRecordSheet.activate
```

I strongly doubt that your version of Office / Windows has anything to do with it. 
Vba is not supported by Microsoft anymore and no further developments to the language are made.

If it's a client, take into account the possibility that this client might have changed the name of the sheet.
In case you properly set the sheet object, this may also be the source of the problem.

**Edit:**

After looking at your file received by mail, I confirm that the above solution fixed the bug.
Replace the entire

```
UserForm_Initialize
```

Subroutine with:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim oRecordSheet As Excel.Worksheet


    Set oRecordSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Expense Report")
    oRecordSheet.Activate
    EnableDisableConrols (False)
    Call FillDropDowns
    Navigator.Max = RecordSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    If RecordSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count = 1 Then
        RowNumber = 1
    Else
        RowNumber = 2
        Call FillDataIntoControls
    End If

End Sub
```

Edit 2: 
The above solution is correct, BUT, if indeed the **codename** of your sheet is set to RecordSheet, you can use this solution too. However, note that the codename can only be used with the workbook.

Comment: I don't think he can change name of the sheet as it require to work with back end and he doesn't know anything about VBA. If you have Windows & office 64 bit I can give you the Macro to check whether you are facing this issue or not.

Comment: If you can upload a sample of the file on the internet, I'll download it and have a look.

Answer (score 1):

I would think there may be missing references.

go to `Tools` -> `References`, and see if any are listed as missing

[image: Example]

Remove the checkmarks there, and the basic stuff like `date` will start working again. If those references are critical to the code you are running, you will have to search out the 64 bit equivalents

More about references - normally resolving "Missing" fixes it, but, from [here](http://forums.devx.com/archive/index.php/t-63738.html)

What you're describing is typical of corrupted references. This can
be caused by a referenced file being a different version or in a different
location between the machine on which the code was developed, and the
client machines. Our company also tries to keep all the machines configured
the same way, but I've found it's essentially impossible to manage.

Open any code module (or open the Debug Window, using Ctrl-G, provided you
haven't selected the "keep debug window on top" option). Select Tools |
References from the menu bar. Examine all of the selected references.

If any of the selected references have "MISSING:" in front of them, unselect
them, and back out of the dialog. If you really need the reference(s) you
just unselected (you can tell by doing a Compile All Modules), go back in
and reselect them.

If none have "MISSING:", select an additional reference at random, back out
of the dialog, then go back in and unselect the reference you just added. If
that doesn't solve the problem, try to unselect as many of the selected
references as you can (Office may not let you unselect them all), back out
of the dialog, then go back in and reselect the references you just
unselected. (NOTE: write down what the references are before you delete
them, because they'll be in a different order when you go back in)

(as a side note, disambigulating as VBA.xxxx will work, since Excel no longer has to
look through all of the references.)

Comment: Still not able to solve this issue. If you have Windows & office 64 bit I can give you the Macro to check whether you are facing this issue or not. Pls help me out

Comment: @tejas, unfortunately, I'm in the process of restoring my home PC, so stuck @ work with XP and 23 bit everything

Answer (score 1):

The first line of your code shows a `UserForm`. Some widely-used form controls (those defined in the `ComCtl` library) don't exist in the 64-bit version of Office so it's highly likely that the `UserForm` is the problem.

There's no easy solution unless you can convince the client to use 32-bit Office instead or alter your `UserForm` so as not to use the affected controls.

Affected controls are: ImageCombo, ImageList, ListView, ProgressBar, Slider, StatusBar, TabStrip (although there is an alternative version of TabStrip in the normal `MSForms` library), Toolbar, Treeview

Details of the problem are discussed in [this thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/officeappcompat/thread/f3a71d69-580b-4cdb-ae0b-d8189e6cfd40) and confirmed [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/choose-the-32-bit-or-64-bit-version-of-office-HA010369476.aspx#_Toc254341419)

Comment: Thank u. I will try to convince him to install 32 bit version. I'm stuck with this problem since last few weeks.